# Docker: Permissions for a mounted volume

Tags: linux, permissions, docker

I have this image in which I mount a volume from the host

```
-v /Users/john/workspace:/data/workspace
```

Inside the container I'm using a user different than root. Now the problem is that it cannot create/modify files inside `/data/workspace` (permission denied). Now I solved it for now to do `chmod -R 777 workspace` on the host. What would be the docker way to solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be solved with [user mapping (issue 7198)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7198), but that same thread include:

> Managed to solve this using the new dockerfile args. It doesn't require doing anything special after the container is built, so I thought I'd share. (Requires Docker 1.9)
>
> In the Dockerfile:

```
# Setup User to match Host User, and give superuser permissions
ARG USER_ID=0
RUN useradd code_executor -u ${USER_ID} -g sudo
RUN echo 'code_executor ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER ${USER_ID}
```

> Then to build:

```
docker build --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u)
```

That way, the user in the container can write in the mounted host volume (no chown/chmod required)

Comment: Thnx a lot for the answer. But there seems to be one issue. Although the whole user setup works, the files in the volume (inside my container) seems to have a different user:group owner: 1000:ftp instead of jeanluca:staff. If I do, for example, `id -u` I get `501`. Maybe this has todo with the fact that all this runs inside virtualBox on a mac. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Then you owuld need to modify (usermod) the user in your Dockerfile, as in (for instance) https://github.com/dgraziotin/osx-docker-mysql/blob/master/run.sh#L12